# Speechrecognition controlled formik form - error with debounce/throttle on analysing new field commands

Tags: reactjs, speech-recognition, formik

I'm working on a react formik form that can be controlled via the speech recognition module.

[image]

There is an issue I am having setting the transcript coming back as it is trying to set the state too fast. I've tried to add a debounce/throttle but it still seems to keep being invoked.

Then there are some bugs like American English/British English and the speech sometimes returns "one" instead of "1" and the form fields itself are sensitive to values being integers or strings.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-fog-fsjy64?file=/src/index.js

VoiceControlledForm - connects the bridge between the speech module and the formik form.

textAnalysis(transcriptText) is where it takes the spoken text and converts it into a command object to control the form if successful - validation and fine-tuning needs to happen here - //currently have set a value overriding it to test

processAnalysis(transcript, listening)

I have tried to only invoke the form control/speech analysis only after the person has stopped talking. I've added this throttle function that has seemed to have helped but without it breaks - but the throttle function needs to stop calling - I cant seem to stabilize the system.

```
console.log("===========><transcript", transcript);

if(transcript.length>0 && !listening){
    console.log("WORDS ARE BEING SPOKEN");
    var that = this;

    var myEfficientFn = throttle(function() {
      console.log("CALLLLED CALLLED");
      that.textAnalysis(transcript)
    }, 1500);

    if(!listening){
      myEfficientFn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways to stabilize the system and prevent too frequent state updates:

```
1.Increase throttle timeout
```

The current 1500ms timeout may still be too short. Try increasing it to something like 3000-5000ms to ensure SpeechRecognition has time to finish each utterance.

```
2.Add debounce instead of throttle
```

```html
const debouncedAnalysis = debounce(this.textAnalysis, 3000) 

debouncedAnalysis(transcript);
```

With debounce, rapid calls will be merged together rather than invoking the last call on a timer. This avoids intermediate state updates.

```
3.  Batch state updates
```

Rather than updating state on every call, you can batch transcripts into a buffer and update state once the buffer reaches a certain threshold.

```html
let transcriptBuffer = []

const handleTranscript = (transcript) => {
  transcriptBuffer.push(transcript)

  if (transcriptBuffer.length >= 5) {
    this.setState({
      transcripts: transcriptBuffer
    })
    
    transcriptBuffer = [] 
  }
}
```

4. Separate speech recognition from state updates

Extract the speech recognition logic into a separate component/module without direct state updates. Then have it emit events/callbacks that can be debounced before updating state.

This separates the frequent transcript updates from component state rendered on screen. The key is inserting some buffering/debouncing layer between the two. Let me know if any of these ideas help or if you have any other questions!